# Check if a nested property has an object that partially matches a target in expect

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, chai

I have an object like this:

```
> const expect = require('chai').expect
> r = {  loadedElementData: { userIdRecord: { name: 'Chiara', surname: 'Fabbietti', id: 1 } }, resolvedIdParamsValues: { users: 1 }, resolvedListFilter: {}, totalLoads: 1 }
```

I can check if an object with specific contents is somewhere deep in `r` -- this doesn't throw:

```
> expect(r).to.have.nested.deep.property('loadedElementData.userIdRecord', { name: "Chiara", surname: "Fabbietti", id: 1 })
```

However, I want to check for *partial* objects. So, I would like something like this to pass even though the comparison object is a partial match:

```
> expect(r).to.have.nested.deep.property('loadedElementData.userIdRecord', { id: 1, name: 'Chiara' })
```

This obviously won't work, since it will check for the object's deep equality.

This in theory should work:

```
expect(r).to.nested.include({'loadedElementData.userIdRecord': { id: 1, name: 'Chiara' } })
```

But doesn't.
This should REALLY work:

```
 expect(r).to.deep.nested.include({ 'loadedElementData.userIdRecord': { id: 1, name: 'Chiara' } })
```

But doesn't.

I can make it work checking ONE property (only 'id'):

```
expect(r).to.nested.include({ 'loadedElementData.userIdRecord.id': 1})
```

But I am limited to check for `id`, and can't check for `name` too at the same time.

I can do this in 2 steps:

```
> expect(r).to.include.nested.property('loadedElementData.userIdRecord')
> expect(r.loadedElementData.userIdRecord).to.include({ id: 1 })
```

But this is a two step process -- can I do it in one step?

Comment: I am starting to suspect that this can't be done

Comment: "*This in theory should work but doesn't*" - have you tried filing a bug report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check their Github issues, maintainers acknowledge that the nested inclusion of an object subset is not working since 2020. Reference: [chai Github](https://github.com/chaijs/chai/issues/1300)

This is the line where Chai decides if doing a deep equality or a strict equality when comparing two objects: https://github.com/chaijs/chai/blob/a8359d3d15779a23a7957a4c52539d48de2763e0/lib/chai/core/assertions.js#L1892.
`_.eql` is a reference to Chai's [deep equal own library implementation](https://github.com/chaijs/deep-eql).

In the `deep-eql` library the flow will reach to this [function](https://github.com/chaijs/deep-eql/blob/3b39bf34bc07a6bc2a2f3be25f984a7a96733ec3/index.js#L414) that does loose equality comparisons but not partial ones.

Comment: Well caught! Thanks for this.

Comment: Sorry bounty awarded now